# What is the SELECT statement equivalent of SHOW ALL SLAVES STATUS?

Tags: mysql, mariadb

The following SQL query in MySQL outputs, in my case just a single row, but with many fields/columns.

```
SHOW ALL SLAVES STATUS;
```

However I need a query that will output just **one** of the fields.

Is there an equivalent query in the form of a SELECT statement, so that I can return only the required field?

e.g. `SELECT field_x FROM some_table;`

Comment: there is a lot of onformation see here https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/performance-schema-replication-tables.html but not all of them

Comment: MariaDB maintains its own comprehensive [knowledge base](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/show-replica-status/) which is slightly more efficient than guess/testing if mysql commands are the same. If there was such a mechanism it would be in the [information_schema](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/information-schema-tables/) however it seems there are none there for replica status. There is a feature request for [Seconds_Behind_Master](https://jira.mariadb.org/browse/MDEV-11123). There are some [slave status variables](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/replication-and-binary-log-status-variables/#slaves_connected).

Comment: So it looks like there isn't a single field mechanism at the moment. Feel free to create a [feature request task](https://jira.mariadb.org). Writing a new information_schema table isn't hugely difficult if it helps you.

Comment: Can you include some more information as to how you are using it? If you're doing it from an application language, `SHOW ALL SLAVES STATUS` returned data just like a select statement with fields and rows and can be treated the same way to only use the field you need.

Comment: maybe something is coming to 10.6 with [MDEV-16437](https://jira.mariadb.org/browse/MDEV-16437)